# Where else can I improve this Merge Sort

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
virtual Indexed<T>& sort(Indexed<T>& data)
{
    //base case

    Vector<T> temp1, temp2, temp3;
    //for (int i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i++)
    //{
    //  cout << data.getElementAt(i) << ", ";
    //}
    mergeSortHelper(data, 0, data.getSize() - 1, temp1, temp2);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.getSize(); i++)
    {
        cout << data.getElementAt(i) << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return data;
}

void mergeSortHelper(Indexed<T>& data, int begin, int end, Vector<T> &left, Vector<T> &right)
{
    //base case, if there is only 1 item in each side, merge them and return
    if ((begin - end) == 0)
    {
        //left.setElementAt(data.getElementAt(begin), 0);
        //left = storage;
        return;

    }
    else
    {
        //Vector<T> right;
        int midPoint = (end + begin) / 2;
        mergeSortHelper(data, begin, midPoint, left, right);
        mergeSortHelper(data, midPoint + 1, end, left, right);
        //perform merging


        int i = 0, leftCounter = 0, leftLimit = (midPoint - begin) + 1, rightCounter = 0, rightLimit = (end - (midPoint + 1)) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < leftLimit; i++)
        {
            if (i < leftLimit)
                left.setElementAt(data.getElementAt(begin + i), i);
            if (i < rightLimit)
                right.setElementAt(data.getElementAt(midPoint + 1 + i), i);
            //cout << left.getElementAt(i) << ", ";
        }
        while (leftCounter < leftLimit || rightCounter < rightLimit)
        {
            if (leftCounter >= leftLimit)
            {
                //done sorting the left side
                data.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), begin + i);
                //temp.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), i);
                rightCounter++;
            }
            else if (rightCounter >= rightLimit)
            {
                //done sorting the right side
                data.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), begin + i);
                //temp.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), i);
                leftCounter++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (left.getElementAt(leftCounter) < right.getElementAt(rightCounter))
                {
                    data.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), begin + i);
                    //temp.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), i);
                    leftCounter++;
                }
                else if (left.getElementAt(leftCounter) > right.getElementAt(rightCounter))
                {
                    data.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), begin + i);
                    //temp.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), i);
                    rightCounter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    data.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), begin + i);
                    //temp.setElementAt(right.getElementAt(rightCounter), i);
                    i++;
                    data.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), begin + i);
                    //temp.setElementAt(left.getElementAt(leftCounter), i);
                    leftCounter++;
                    rightCounter++;

                }

            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    //return temp;
```

Where else can I improve to make the sort faster? I've been speding so much time on this just make it to work properly. But as I recall from class quick sort and merge sort are O(NlogN) but my quickSort code above is not that efficient, it takes 2.5 times longer to sort the same number of item.

Comment: Being both O(NlogN) will not mean that they will have the same speed.

Comment: Vanilla Quicksort has worst-case complexity O(n*n). Of course, the complexity doesn't say much about how well it will behave on practical sized use and it also involves an arbitrarily large constant.

Comment: @Kuhl - it's still correct to say quicksort has expected complexity O(n log n). Big O says you're specifying an asymptotic upper bound - it doesn't say what the function you're bounding describes. Though TBH if your view is that for performance, the worst-case is an upper-bound on all the other upper-bounds, I've often thought that myself.

Comment: Are you writing this for any practical purpose or just the pleasure of writing the code and learning? I recently had a case on a large dataset where I needed a specific subset on an almost sorted range. Sorting took too long so I used two calls to `partition` and sorted just the returned range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly complex. There are two parts to a merge sort: divide and merge. Each should be a function.

You should also have a top-level function (the public interface that your users will use).

For maximum speed, you should allocate all the extra memory you will need *once*, in your top-level function, and pass it down for use by your lower level functions. (Use a vector and resize it to the length of your data.)

Don't bottom out when (end - begin == 0) -- that's a pair of wasted function calls. Stop when their difference is *two*. Sort the two and start working back up the tree.

Your merge algorithm should all be in a single function, and you can clean it up somewhat. The basic merge algorithm is:

- while both A and B have elements:

  - if A's first element is less than B's first element:

    - remove A's and append it to the result
    - else remove B's and append it to the result
- append whichever sequence still has elements (A or B) to the result

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, be aware that Hoare named his new sort "quicksort" for good reason--it was significantly faster than other sorts known at the time (which included Merge-sort). In other words, don't expect a merge sort to keep up with a quicksort (as a general rule), almost regardless of how well it's implemented.

That said, you *can* usually implement a merge sort a bit better than you have here. In particular, a merge sort can be implemented "bottom up" instead of "top down". Right now, your function basically splits the array in half, then calls itself to sort each half of the array.

So, you do a lot of recursive calls, that basically all each does is compute the index of the middle of the part of the array that needs to be sorted. That adds quite a bit of overhead to a relatively trivial computation.

In the end, the result of that is pretty much a foregone conclusion anyway though. You always keep making recursive calls until a partition is only one or two elements (or so).

As far as the extra space you need goes, one extra array the same size as the input is plenty (even that isn't absolutely necessary, but the techniques for in-place merging add complexity, so they're harder to write correctly, and run slower anyway).

Since you know you're going to split the array until you get to only two items anyway, you can just start from there in the first place. Simply take the first pair of elements, and swap them if they're out of order. Continue with pairs for the rest of the array.

Then you're in the merging phase: merge the first pair with the second pair, the third with the fourth, and so on. Continue for the remainder of the array. Repeat with that process until you've sorted the entire array.

You generally don't want to start with just two items in a partition though. You'd generally want to start by using an insertion sort on (say) 10 items at a time, then go into the merging phase (though the precise size isn't critical).

Comment: This approach, as described, will suffer a lot from cache misses when the data is large, since it doesn't try to exploit any locality.

Comment: Also, another thing to keep in mind is that all other things being equal, balanced merges outperforms imbalanced merges.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, at most, constant factors - not asymptotic performance. IOW there's a strong risk of getting into premature micro-optimizations. That said, it's still worth learning how for when it's not so premature, so...

First, high-performance sorts are AFAICT always hybrid algorithms. Those terrible O(n^2) algorithms like insertion sort are actually very good provided n is small enough, so practical sorting algorithms tend to switch strategy when n gets small. If you're sorting a million items and your strategy switch happens at n=10, it might sound like your only benefiting for a trivial 10-item sort anyway, but that happens around 100,000 times during your million-item sort so the cumulative benefit can pay off nicely.

There's even a case for very small n for a hard-coded which-permutation-am-I-in nested set of ifs so that, for each permutation, a pre-determined optimal set of moves/swaps are applied. For example, for n=3 there are 6 possible orderings of the items - 6 cases to detect, 6 sets of moves/swaps to figure out. For n=4 that's now 24 cases, so already getting very painful, and don't forget that too much code slows things down too.

Once you're sure the algorithm itself is right, see what work can be moved out of inner loops. That has a double-benefit - first, that work is done less often. Second, the inner loop itself gets simpler so the compiler can optimize it better. The price is of course that the overall complexity of the code increases, and beware - the compiler should already be doing some of this for you, so it's easy to not only waste time doing the compilers work for it, but to introduce bugs by getting it wrong and to block other compiler optimizations and end up with slower code.

Regressions tests, measure performance before and after, if in doubt check the generated machine code, etc etc.

One obvious target, though - it's convenient to have a single loop and on each iteration check whether one/other of the sources to merge are exhausted, but that's also inefficient. So when either source is exhausted, detect that once and use a special-case loop to finish processing the other source.

Also, to avoid doing that exhaustion check with every loop, if the source array with the least items in has k items, you can do k iterations safely with no exhaustion checks. So have an outer loop where you check what k is, and an inner loop over k items with no exhaustion checks.

The second point keeps the inner loop simple for most of the merge, with less benefit towards the end (as k gets smaller each time you check it). It also adds extra complexity - an outer loop - so it's not for free. The first point means you have a simple inner loop for finishing up at the end.

An alternative approach might be to have an inner loop that takes only from one source until either it's exhausted or the next item is too large, then another inner loop taking from the other source.

Finally, it's very *very* hard to beat `std::sort` unless you know something special about your particular platform (GPU-based sorting?) or your data (an O(n) integers-only sorting algorithm?). Basically, whoever wrote your standard library implementation already tried all this and more.

Answer (score 0):

These examples are reasonably fast, on my system, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz, it takes less than 0.4 second to sort 4 million pseudo random 32 bit unsigned integers. Bottom up uses iteration to generate the indices used to merge runs, while top down uses recursion to generate the indices, a small overhead, since most of the time is spent merging data, not generating indices.

Bottom Up:

```
template <typename T>
void BottomUpMergeSort(T a[], T b[], size_t n);
template <typename T>
void BottomUpCopy(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr);
template <typename T>
void BottomUpMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee);

template <typename T>
void MergeSort(T a[], size_t n)             // entry function
{
    if(n < 2)                               // if size < 2 return
        return;
    T *b = new T[n];
    BottomUpMergeSort(a, b, n);
    delete[] b;
}

size_t GetPassCount(size_t n)               // return # passes
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for(size_t s = 1; s < n; s <<= 1)
        i += 1;
    return(i);
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpMergeSort(T a[], T b[], size_t n)
{
size_t s = 1;                               // run size 
    if(GetPassCount(n) & 1){                // if odd number of passes
        for(s = 1; s < n; s += 2)           // swap in place for 1st pass
            if(a[s] < a[s-1])
                std::swap(a[s], a[s-1]);
        s = 2;
    }
    while(s < n){                           // while not done
        size_t ee = 0;                      // reset end index
        while(ee < n){                      // merge pairs of runs
            size_t ll = ee;                 // ll = start of left  run
            size_t rr = ll+s;               // rr = start of right run
            if(rr >= n){                    // if only left run
                rr = n;
                BottomUpCopy(a, b, ll, rr); //   copy left run
                break;                      //   end of pass
            }
            ee = rr+s;                      // ee = end of right run
            if(ee > n)
                ee = n;
            BottomUpMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                    // swap a and b
        s <<= 1;                            // double the run size
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpCopy(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr)
{
    while(ll < rr){                         // copy left run
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        ll++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index
    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)                   //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr)                   //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Top Down. The co-recursive calls (...AtoA, ...AtoB) avoid unneeded copying of data. TopDownMerge() is the same as BottomUpMerge().

```
template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee);
template <typename T>
void TopDownMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee);

template <typename T>
void MergeSort(T a[], size_t n)             // entry function
{
    if(n < 2)                               // if size < 2 return
        return;
    T *b = new T[n];
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    delete[] b;
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1)                  // if size == 1 return
        return;
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
    TopDownMerge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);     // merge b to a
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownSplitMergeAtoB(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if((ee - ll) == 1){                 // if size == 1 copy a to b
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        return;
    }
    size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
    TopDownSplitMergeAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
    TopDownMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);     // merge a to b
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index
    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee)                   //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr)                   //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```